# hide and unhide a label in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to hide and unhide a label in my asp.net project, I´m using C# and JavaScript.

Name of my label:

```
Label2
```

I tryed like this:

```
if (useraddress == "123")
     {
         Label2ShowText.Visible = true;
     }
     else
     {
         Label2ShowText.Visible = false;
     }
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Please post the complete code.

Comment: No offence, just out of curiosity: Why put `Label2ShowText`?

Comment: is it Label2ShowText.Visible or Label2.Visible

Comment: asp.net is completely new to me, I just saw something like this     Label2ShowText.

Comment: Where is that code supposed to run? CodeBehind or client side?

Comment: Try if(useraddress.Equals("123")). Assuming that your Label name is right

Comment: @ray What is the benefit of that? Did you mean `if(useraddress.Equals("123", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`?

Comment: the IF is working, I just Need help with the label

Answer (score 2):

if name is *Label2* then your code should be

```
if (useraddress == "123")
    Label2.Visible = true;
else
    Label2.Visible = false;
```

Comment: If I write it like this there is a blue zigzag line below and it´s not working.

Comment: It´s saying 'The Name Label2 does not exist in the current context' but I added it with designer in VB, it is there whit ID Label2.

Comment: @Julius How did you add "it with designer in VB" and you're saying in your question that your code-behind is in C#?

Comment: Im ment VS (visual Studio) via "Tools" and set the properties to Label2 and the code is written in C# yes

Comment: @Julius If you add it in the designer, that does not mean you did in VB. Anyway, delete it and check the code, do you now see "blue zigzag" under **Label2ShowText**?

Answer (score 0):

The name of your lablel as you said is `Label2`, while you are refering to `Label2ShowText`, look:

```
Label2ShowText.Visible = true;
```

Change it to:

```
if (useraddress == "123")
{
  Label2.Visible = true;
}
else
{
  Label2.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Web; using System.Web.UI; using System.Web.UI.WebControls; using System.Xml; using System.Data; using System.Globalization; using System.Data.SqlClient; do I have to add something in here?

Answer (score 0):

You refered the label as `Label2` ..But you used `Label2ShowText` instead...

```
Label2.Visible = true;
```